# Python parsing Google Contacts xml

Tags: python, xml

Here's a sample of my XML file I want to parse. How can I get *gd:fullName* and *address* from it? The problem is in some situations I have the name field and sometimes I don't. Any help?
I use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

 root.findall('./{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry/{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title'):
        print item.attrib
```

but it just gives me empty dictionaries. And I haven't used the gdata library, so I want to extract the data myself. Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed gd:etag="&quot;Rn84fzVSLyt7I2A9XRVbFkwOQAE.&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <id>moha****ee@gmail.com</id>
 <updated>2015-08-03T15:12:37.137Z</updated>
 <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
 <title>Mohammad Amin's Contacts</title>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mohamma***ee%40gmail.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mohamm***aee%40gmail.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moha****ee%40gmail.com/full/batch"/>
 <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moham***ee%40gmail.com/full?max-results=25"/>
 <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moha****aee%40gmail.com/full?max-results=25&amp;start-index=26"/>
 <author>
  <name>Mohammad Amin</name>
  <email>moha****ee@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
 <generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>131</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
 <entry gd:etag="&quot;SXc5cTNQJit7I2A9XRRbGEsPQQY.&quot;">
  <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moh***ee%40gmail.com/base/15281000e768a31</id>
  <updated>2015-04-12T19:07:08.929Z</updated>
  <app:edited xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">2015-04-12T19:07:08.929Z</app:edited>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <title>Sina Ghazi</title>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/moh***aee%40gmail.com/15****a31" gd:etag="&quot;WR1-e34pSit7I2BlWW4TbChNHHg6LF88WhE.&quot;"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moham****aee%40gmail.com/full/1528****8a31"/>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mohamm***ee%40gmail.com/full/15***a31"/>
  <gd:name>
   <gd:fullName>Si***i</gd:fullName>
   <gd:givenName>Si***a</gd:givenName>
   <gd:familyName>G***zi</gd:familyName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="si***i@gmail.com" primary="true"/>
  <gContact:website href="http://www.google.com/profiles/1167****31" rel="profile"/>
 </entry>
```

Comment: For some reason I am not able to retrieve google contacts xml file anymore. I get a `Login Required` error.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No.... I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: Is your access token valid?

Comment: It always worked, and just stoped working. Never used 'tokens', but username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems going on here.

You don't show all your code, but if `root` is the result of...

```
with open('data.xml') as fd:
    doc = etree.parse(fd)

root = doc.getroot()
```

...then you're never going to find any `entry` elements:

```
>>> print root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')
[]
```

Because the root element doesn't *contain* any `entry` elements.  You will find `title` elements:

```
>>> print root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title')
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title at 0x7ff8b3d166c8>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title at 0x7ff8b3d162d8>]
```

But looking at `.attrib` on these will yield empty dictionaries, because the `title` elements have no attributes:

```
<title>Si***azi</title>
```

If you want `gd:fullName`, you would need something like:

```
>>> root.findall('*/{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}fullName')
[<Element {http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}fullName at 0x7ff8b04a83f8>]
```

Note that this is using a different namespace
(`http://schemas.google.com/g/2005`) from the default namespace
(`http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`).

There is no `address` element that I can see, but you could use the
above to get the `gd:email` element and then extract the `address`
attribute.

**Update**

Consider instead using the `xpath` method and a namespaces dictionary:

```
>>> namespaces={'atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
... 'gd': 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'}
>>> root.xpath('//atom:title', namespaces=namespaces)
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title at 0x7fd63aa30b90>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title at 0x7fd642b18ea8>]
>>> root.xpath('//gd:fullName', namespaces=namespaces)
[<Element {http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}fullName at 0x7fd63a5c5170>]
```

Or, using an explicit path instead of `//`:

```
>>> root.xpath('/atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:title', namespaces=namespaces)
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title at 0x7fd642b18ea8>]
```

Comment: You're right. I edited my post. I think there was a mistake in my sample xml, because root.findall('*/{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}fullName') gives me empty lists too.

Comment: Can you please take another look? Thank you

Comment: I was using your sample data when testing this answer.  Your updated post has broken xml...there is an opening `<feed>` but no closing `</feed>` (I'm assuming it's just missing a final closing `</feed>` and nothing else).  Having a `<feed>` element wrapping everything that was in your earlier example will of course change the paths you pass to `findall`.